# SSH hang bringing WireGuard client up

Tags: linux, networking, wireguard

I have a headless Ubuntu system that is dedicated to being a WireGuard client to other devices on the LAN (currently to one device). I.e., it's intended to forward through the tunnel all enp1s0 (ETH1) input that is not addressed to the local subnet -- all non-SSH input. The other end of the tunnel is a WG server on a cloud VPS.

Here's the SSH transcript of bringing up WireGuard:

```
vpnpeer:~$ sudo wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.4.0.2 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] ip -4 route add 10.4.0.1/32 dev wg0
[#] ip rule add not to 192.168.1.0/24 iif enp1s0 table 248
[#] ip route add default table 248 via 10.4.0.1 dev wg0
```

At this point the SSH session is hung: it doesn't respond to keyboard input such as Enter or Ctrl-C. From another terminal an attempt to start another SSH session results in a timeout. After an interval of ~2 minutes this line appears after the last one shown above:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

...and the SSH client terminal shows a prompt. During the initial hard hang the Ubuntu system doesn't respond to holding down its power button to power it down; I remove and re-insert its power plug to reboot it. Although if I wait until the SSH error message displays, the problem system's power button does power it down.

Here's the WG config file content:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.4.0.2
DNS = 1.1.1.2, 1.0.0.2

# filter to pass only nonlocal traffic input on ethernet...
PostUp = ip rule add not to 192.168.1.0/24 iif enp1s0 table 248
# ...to the other end of the tunnel via the WG interface at this end
PostUp = ip route add default table 248 via 10.4.0.1 dev %i
##############The previous command is the last one displayed
##############before SSH hangs

# to local subnet, in from tunnel:
PostUp = ip rule add to 192.168.1.0/24 iif %i table 359
# to any, next hop = gw via ETH1:              
PostUp = ip route add default table 359 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 
    
PostUp = ufw route allow in on enp1s0 out on %i
PostUp = ufw route allow in on %i out on enp1s0

####### PreDown commands omitted

[Peer]
PublicKey = ... 
AllowedIPs = 10.4.0.1   # address of virtual remote end of tunnel
Endpoint = ...
```

Would appreciate any assistance!

Comment: You have not told us what you mean by "hang bringing wireguard up".  Have you looked at DNS, does the system eventually respond?  Do old sessions just stop but you can make new ones?

Comment: @davidgo, indeed I omitted too much context. I have edited the question to add a lot. "Eventually" is subjective, but no, it never responds. As noted in the edited version, the hang is (what I call) hard for the first minute or so before an error message displays.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # ...to the other end of the tunnel via the WG interface at this end
> PostUp = ip route add default table 248 via 10.4.0.1 dev %i
> ```

WireGuard tunnels are "layer3 tunnels" without MAC addresses, so it is not possible to use routes that select a specific gateway with `via` – all such routes behave like direct `dev wg0` routes. (The same applies to GRE tunnels, PPP interfaces, and 'tun' interfaces.)

The problem with that is: Lacking L2 addresses, WireGuard uses `AllowedIPs=` to internally select which peer to forward the packets to. However, unlike 'via', this is based on the IP header, not on the L2 header – so only packets whose *final destination IP* matches AllowedIPs will be allowed through the tunnel.

This means that if you want to use a WireGuard peer for your default route, you must have that peer's AllowedIPs set to `0.0.0.0/0` (and `::/0` for IPv6).

Doing so limits the tunnel to one peer; if you want to have multiple default routes via several different nexthops, you will need separate WireGuard tunnels (one for each peer).

(Note that wg-quick will automatically insert routes via %i based on AllowedIPs, so make sure to specify `Table = 248` so that they go into the correct table. You can then remove the manual route addition from PostUp. Alternatively, disable wg-quick's automation via `Table = off`.)

Comment: (Thanks^2)  ••In ordinary/traditional terminology I have two VPN clients, a Mac (occasionally, for selected web traffic), and a data server; and one VPN server, a WG instance on a cloud VPS. The local WG box and the data server are both headless, so I need SSH access to them from the Mac.  I'm inferring that I need two tunnels. Does that mean two local and two remote instances of WG, each with a .conf file?

Comment: Only if you want to route 0.0.0.0/0 *to* both clients at the same time (via rules on the server). In your case it sounds like  the server only routes non-conflicting /24s and /32s to each client, and it's the *clients* that route 0.0.0.0/0 to the server – they won't conflict because they already are different machines.

Comment: There are probably other problems related to routing besides what I described, but right now I didn't have time to fully understand your whole network layout. I think you also want to make your rules on the VPS more specific regarding the `from` address, so that it doesn't try to use wg0 for the SSH packets that come from its WAN address.

Comment: Generally: I think you've provided enough info for me to have another go at the .conf files. Specifically, yikes! I hadn't yet realized I'd have the SSH issue on the VPS as well as locally. I don't think I can filter on address, at least as long as I have a local WAN address that's assigned by ISP's DHCP. Maybe I can filter on protocol and port,  as in the example I asked about in another question here that you answered.

Comment: You could do the opposite, e.g. `ip rule add from <wireguard_prefix> table <wireguard_table>` for correctly responding to connections via WG, while keeping WAN default route for everything else.

Comment: Do I understand correctly... <wireguard_prefix> is the virtual address of the tunnel interface that's local-to-me, i.e. in my case (see .conf in question) 10.4.0.2/32, and <wireguard_table> is the table number I've chosen to put on the right side of a `table =` command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137067/discussion-between-brec-and-user1686).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in this:

```
ip rule add not to 192.168.1.0/24 iif enp1s0 table 248
```

What you really want for `iif` is `lo`, which is used to refer to the "output" traffics (outbound traffics originated from this host itself, while `iif enp1s0` refers to traffics from other hosts arriving at `enp1s0`).

Having the above rule means that unless there is another rule of lower priority (higher precedence) *that is relevant to the case*, `to 192.168.1.0/24 iif lo` traffics will lookup table `248` (which contains a default route that leads to the WG tunnel), since those traffics are **"not"** `to 192.168.1.0/24 iif enp1s0`.

Similarly, the rule `to 192.168.1.0/24 iif %i table 359` added later (lower priority / higher precedence, when no `priority` specified) does **NOT** cover the case `to 192.168.1.0/24 iif lo` (because of `iif %i`) either.

---

The truth is in your case you hardly need to set up any IP rule or routes manually, unless e.g. you do not want this "relay client" itself to use the WG server for *Internet* traffics (more precisely, traffics that are not covered by any route with prefix length > 0), or there are non-default routes that you *actually* need to override.

By default (when `Table=` is not explicitly set to value other than `auto`) [wg-quick will cause any traffics that are originally covered by the `default` route in the `main` table to be routed into the tunnel instead, while traffics covered by non-default routes (prefix length > 0) will not be affected](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-tools/blob/v1.0.20210914/src/wg-quick/linux.bash#L223-L225).

Although due to a flaw in the order of `ip` commands executed by wg-quick, you'll still suffer from a disconnection when it is being set up. If that irritates you, modify `wg-quick` (it's just a bash script) by placing the `route` line highlighted in the link above after the two `rule` lines that are before it, i.e. from:

```
cmd ip $proto route add "$1" dev "$INTERFACE" table $table
cmd ip $proto rule add not fwmark $table table $table
cmd ip $proto rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
```

to

```
cmd ip $proto rule add not fwmark $table table $table
cmd ip $proto rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
cmd ip $proto route add "$1" dev "$INTERFACE" table $table
```

(Certainly that will get reset whenever the wireguard-tools package is updated in your system.)

---

I'm not exactly sure what you really want for with:

> to local subnet, in from tunnel

Are you actually trying to allow remote hosts (WG clients that are NOT one of your LAN hosts) to be able to reach your LAN hosts via WireGuard client to other devices on the LAN? Let me know if that's the case, and I'll come up with more on that.

Comment: Certainly this is all assuming `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0` specified for the WG server `[peer]` section on the client's conf.

Comment: I made several changes since my last comment to @User1686 's answer: Yes, now `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0`; I deleted `iif enp1s0` from the first `PostUp = ip` rule; I deleted the other three `PostUp = ip` rules. The two relevant `wg-quick up` "[*]" output lines still seem out of order: `ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 248` followed by `ip rule add not to 192.168.50.0/24 table 248`, but now there's no SSH hang. ... In a digitalocean setup tutorial have seen the `not fwmark` and `suppress_prefixlength 0` lines you linked to,  but I'm not seeing them here. (cont'd next comment)

Comment: Your ending question: I think the answer is no. My WG client is intended to be a VPN server (but not a "WireGuard server") to a couple of other LAN hosts. The only remote WG system is the true WireGuard server (i.e., no endpoint in [Peer]) on the cloud VPS. In sum, situation now is although no SSH hang, apparently no tunnel connectivity. Just about to do some packet sniffing...